# How to get and install g723 codecs for sip applications?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, codec, sip, jitsi

I install an ubuntu desktop in my company network (windows network) that use SIP on software phone and hard SIP phones.

I use Jitsi that is a good client for SIP and works well with others software phones on the network but fails to decode streams from and to hard SIP phones.

It looks like the main codec for decode RAW data from hard phones is g723 / g729 but I didn't found any resources on it for get it for linux/ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of *G.723* or *G.729* requires a license fee and/or royalty fee for the patents that cover the algorithms. Open Source and free SIP solutions are unable to include the mentioned codecs.

You will need other softphone that include the codecs and the license. It means non-free software.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have the same issue, we found a workaround (after taking into account the right jcbermu's response):

We disabled the SIP [`canreinvite` configuration option](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+canreinvite) for all linux client machines onto the SIP server, thus it does the encoding/decoding tasks. The problem is the made necessary scalability of the SIP server compared to the number of linux machines. But then it works with opensource SIP client.

Comment: You are using the SIP Server to make transcoding also. It's a good option for a few simultaneous calls but it won't scale if your number of Linux clients increase.